# Replacing Component in Tabs Routing Angular Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, angular2-routing

In the generic ionic tabs template, I am trying to replace tab 2 with a component. I keep getting this error despite having PeopleComponent imported:

My error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component PeopleComponent is not part 
of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
Error: Component PeopleComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has 
not been imported into your module.
```

People Component is very simple and does not give errors. I have tried removing the import from one or the other, but that doesn't work. Not sure what to do.

App Module:

```
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ...
  PeopleComponent,
]
...
```

Tabs Routing Module:

```
import { PeopleComponent } from './../path/people/people.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
 {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
 {
    path: 'tab1',
    loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'tab2',
    component: PeopleComponent
    // loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'tab3',
    loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
]
},
{
   path: '',
   redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
   pathMatch: 'full'
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}

Tabs Module:

```
import { PeopleComponent } from './../path/people/people.component';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { TabsPageRoutingModule } from './tabs-routing.module';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    TabsPageRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [TabsPage]
})
export class TabsPageModule {}
```

Comment: In tabs module add PeopleComponent to imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit:

Instead of doing what was mentioned below, it is better to remove the unwanted modules that ionic tabs starter template creates.

Here is the [commit](https://github.com/harishmaddali/so-tabs-starter-fix/commit/cd40d8f2da468e7ffce88ff85ac273fdc943439a) I have done which removes the unnecessary modules and makes the application simpler.

You can do the similar thing to your application and make it simpler.

#### Old Answer

You will have to add the `PeopleComponent` inside `declarations` of the `TabsPageModule` and not the `AppModule`.

The problem is `TabsPageModule` doesn't know about the `PeopleComponent` because it has been declared in the `AppModule`. Unless you export the `PeopleComponent` in AppModule and import the AppModule inside the `TabsPageModule`, `PeopleComponent` won't be available for use.

Instead of doing all this, as mentioned on the first line, simply remove `PeopleComponent` from `AppModule` declarations and add it to the declarations in `TabsPageModule`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I went with the second option because I am using the PeopleComponent in other places. I was given this error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead.
Error: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead.

Comment: The problem with the Tabs starter template is that, it adds unnecessary modules. There is not need to have a modules for `TabsPage` and individual tabs. It is better to remove those modules and directly declare the tabs and routes in the parent route module.

Comment: @DarrowHartman I have updated the answer to show how you can edit your current structure and remove unnecessary modules. Check if that helps you and resolves your issue.